# OnTap for a custom overlay says that my context is out of scope, why?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my overlay toast information when an item is tapped, however when I try to give it the context of the activity it will be in the compiler is yelling at me saying that ElonMap.this is out of scope and I do not know why.

```
public boolean onTap(int i) {
 Toast.makeText(ElonMap.this, items.get(i).getSnippet(),
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 return(true);
    }
```

Comment: What is ElonMap? Where is onTop located? We need a LOT more information.

Comment: I presume that the class ElonMap is a MapActivity and that the specific onTap method which you refer to above is actually inside the ElonMap class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `onTap()` is not a method on `ElonTap`, nor on an inner class of `ElonTap`, and hence cannot reference `ElonTap`.

Comment: Correct, this is a custom overlay in a separate class so how can I allow a toast to appear in my map activity?